# Cognito Authentication Flow (and not OAuth Flows)

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito

**Cognito Userpool question**

regarding **Authentication Flows** (e.g **ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH , ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH** )
(Please note - I’m NOT talking about OAuth Flows. I am talking about Authentication Flows like ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH).

What’s the importance of this? If I select SOME value or NO for Authentication flow from cognito UI nothing changes for me in terms of output. I still get the valid  Auth Token back from Cognito.

Then what is the importance of Authentication Flow?

For example, I am using following endpoint to get the token:

```
curl POST https://<cognito_domain>/oauth2/token
```

1. **No** Authentication Flow chosen

> curl POST https://<cognito_domain>/oauth2/token

I get valid token back. There is no as a end-user any experience change.

2. **ALLOW_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH** Authentication Flow chosen

> curl POST https://<cognito_domain>/oauth2/token

I get valid token back. There is no as a end-user any experience change.

3. **ALLOW_USER_SRP_AUTH** Authentication Flow chosen

> curl POST https://<cognito_domain>/oauth2/token

I get valid token back. There is no as a end-user any experience change.

Then question is, what’s happening when I choose Authentication Flow?

[image]